# What is the best way to share static/config data in a Laravel/Vue.js project

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, webpack, vue.js

I'm currently working on a Laravel/Vue.js project where I need to use the same data (i.e. Static list of Operating Systems) both in the backend and frontend. So far these are the different options I've thought of:

- Duplicate data both in my Laravel and vue.js projects.
- Load the data into the frontend through the API
- Share, the data through a common static config file and possibly preload the data into Vue at processing time (currently using webpack)

The third options seem to be the best of them all as it avoid duplication of data and the need to make unnecessary requests and wondering if it's possible to accomplish with existing tools.

Comment: How do you define "best"? This is sounds very subjective/opinion-based to me.

Comment: Hi @DavidStockinger - should have been clearer there. Best here refers to avoiding data duplication and having to maintain it in two places as in the first option. The second option is the less performant of both options as this means having to make an API request for the static data needed which may get excessive  depending on the size of the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the best way would depend on the specifics of the app.

I typically prefer #3 as that's the "**Laravel way**". Use variables prefixed with `MIX_` in your .env file and access them in the frontend using `process.env.MIX_VARIABLE_NAME` as described in the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mix#environment-variables). Access them in the backend using the `env` [helper](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-env)

Although arrays are not supported, you can always construct them in the backend and frontend like so:

```
$config = [     
    env('KEY1') => [
        env('KEY_ONE') => env('VALUE_ONE'),     
        env('KEY_TWO') => env('VALUE_TWO')  
    ],
    ...
};
```

Comment: Thanks @Paras. I wasn't aware of this method for injecting env variable into mix. To what extent can this method be used? I can see it being helpful for single-values and "environment" configurations but seems limited for it to be used for static non-environment-configs data. Also as far as I'm aware arrays aren't supported by dotenv.

Comment: Have updated my answer for a method to construct arrays. They aren't supported out of the box but it's pretty easy to construct them from single values. You can also use prefixes for the variables to identify what parent they relate to

Comment: Thanks @Paras. I've accepted this answer as it is a viable solution and learnt something new. For my use case, I've decided to approach this by generating a static js file that contains all static data needed by the app and embedding into the application header for use in Vue.js. An ultimate solution that I thought of would require the development of a webpack preloader that evaluates the arrays in the laravel config files and translate/inject them into a js file for use by the Vue.js app